# Issue related to Getting reply using PING Command in Network

Tags: networking

My Computer is connected in network using `Ethernet cable.`

My Computer's IP Address : `192.168.2.115`

when i try to `ping` other computers on network using `Ping` command, i am getting reply successfully.

But when other computer try to `Ping` my computer using `Ping` command they doesn't get reply.

what is the reason? and how to solve it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

mostly you have enabled firewall on your computer , if it is windows firewall you can disable it from control panel